# how to remove bad lines using cmd in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `csv.gz` file whose content looks like:

```
bogusfile <- '1,2,3
1,2,3
2,,3
1,2,3,4
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3'
```

I **know** there are only 3 columns but sometimes an extra bogus 4th column pops up and messes my parsing with `fread`.

Fortunately there is a `cmd` command in `fread`. How can we use it to discard all the lines that contains exactly more than 2 commas (these would be the offending rows with extra coumns).

Something like `fread(cmd = ' linux magic to clean myfile.csv.gz')`?

I was not able to make it work.
What do you think?
Thanks!

Comment: `egrep -v "[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*," filename` should remove lines with three (or more) commas. (This does *not* deal with embedded commas such as in a string.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```r
data.table::fread(cmd = 'c:/Rtools/bin/grep.exe -E -v "[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*," Noobie.txt')
#    V1 V2 V3
# 1:  1  2  3
# 2:  1  2  3
# 3:  2 NA  3
# 4:  1  2  3
# 5:  1  2  3
# 6:  1  2  3
```

I had to use `grep -E` vice `egrep` because of windows ... and I had to specify the full path to `grep` because RTools is not in my default path. If you are on something other than windows, you should be able to shorten this to `fread(cmd="egrep -v ...")`. (And make sure you are in the correct directory or provide relative/absolute path to the file.)

The regex `"[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*,"` is a bit literal, it can be shorted to `"([^,]*,){3,}"`, which says

- `([^,]*,)` group of non-comma followed by a comma
- `{3,}` three or more
- `-v` omit lines that match the pattern

so

```r
data.table::fread(cmd = 'c:/Rtools/bin/grep.exe -E -v "([^,]*,){3,}" Noobie.txt')
```

If the data is compressed (gz), on non-Windows platforms you can choose from among:

```
gzip -cd filename.csv.gz | egrep -v "([^,]*,){3,}"
gunzip -c filename.csv.gz | egrep -v "([^,]*,){3,}"
zgrep -E -V "([^,]*,){3,}" filename.csv.gz
```

It won't work on windows since `system` and similar functionality on R on windows does not use `bash` for its shell, so the `|` in-fix operator doesn't do what one expects. There might be a way to get `|` to work in `system` et al, but I don't know how to get it to work with `data.table::fread(..., cmd=)`.

Admittedly untested since ... I'm on Windows :-(

Comment: No. That would require a piped command (e.g., `gzcat filename | egrep -v ...`), but it does not appear that `data.table::fread` supports that premise.

Comment: Is your data "large-ish"? If not, you can always read it into R directly with `readLines("filename.csv.gz")` and the filter in R, eventually parsing with `data.table::fread(text=)`. (I'm inferring, though, that you are using `fread` partly for size.)

Comment: yes... the data is a bit large.... I thought I would be able to pipe here. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Actually ... what OS are you on? The piping problem might be windows-specific. If not windows, try `data.table::fread(cmd = 'gzip -cd filename.csv.gz | egrep -v "([^,]*,){3,}"')`

Comment: I will try right now. Do you think running egrep will slow down things a lot?

Comment: Not really, given the general need for regex (counting commas), I don't know of anything faster other than custom C code. It'll still be significantly faster than doing it in R.

Comment: If you have `zgrep` (usually a shell script), then you might even be able to do `data.table::fread(cmd = 'zgrep -E -v "([^,]*,){4,}" filename.txt.gz')`.